# Biometrico veridis

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema biométrico para cadastrar e identificar os clientes. Estou me baseando no Veridis Biometric só que ao solicitar a identificação ele está gerando este erro:

> The format is not supported, invalid or could not be determined automatically (Error #-9)

Buscando as digitais do banco de dados ele sempre da esse erro e não consigo solucionar esse problema.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat.Encoding;

import veridis.biometric.BiometricIdentification;
import veridis.biometric.BiometricSDK;
import veridis.biometric.BiometricTemplate;
import veridis.biometric.samples.applet.Base64;

import veridis.biometric.BiometricImage;
import veridis.biometric.BiometricTemplate;
import veridis.biometric.BiometricException.FeatureNotAvailableForFreeException;
import veridis.biometric.BiometricException.FeatureNotLicensedException;
import veridis.biometric.BiometricException.UnsupportedBiometricModalityException;
import veridis.sample.util.ButtonLayout;

import org.json.*;

public class dbAccess {

    private static final BiometricTemplate AddTemplate = null;
    protected static Connection con = null;
    protected static Statement stm = null;
    protected static int minimumThreshold = 40;
    public static Object Console;

    public static boolean AddTemplate(BiometricTemplate template) throws SQLException {

        String str = "http://192.168.51.199/ponto/index.php/JSON/listaTemplate/";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(str);

            Scanner scan;
            try {

                scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());

                String str2 = new String();
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    str2 += scan.nextLine();
                }
                scan.close();

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str2);

                JSONArray elenco = obj.getJSONArray("usuarios");
                for (int i = 0; i < elenco.length(); i++) {

                    String[] tmp = elenco.getString(i).split("-");

                    BiometricTemplate tempBD;

                    try {

                        tempBD = new BiometricTemplate((Base64.decode(tmp[1])));
                        System.out.println(template.getData());
                        System.out.println(Base64.decode(tmp[1]));
                        Object bytes = template;
                        System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes);
                        if (tempBD.match(tempBD) > minimumThreshold) {
                            System.out.println("Achou");
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        return false;

                    }

                    //System.out.println(spl[0]);
                    //usersmodel.addElement(elenco.getString(i));
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*if(res.next()){       
         try{

         BiometricTemplate tempBD = new BiometricTemplate((Base64.decode(res.getString("template"))));

         if (tempBD.match(template) > minimumThreshold)
         return 1;
         }
         catch(Exception e ){
         System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         return -1;
         }*/
        System.exit(0);
        return true;

    }
    /*Function to get Template from database*/

    public static BiometricTemplate getTemplate(BiometricTemplate template, String id) throws SQLException {

        if (con == null) {
            connectToDB();
        }
        if (stm == null) {
            stm = con.createStatement();
        }

        String query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where id = \"" + id + "\"";

        ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(query);
        if (res.next()) {
            try {

                BiometricTemplate tempBD = new BiometricTemplate((Base64.decode(res.getString("Template"))));

                return tempBD;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /*Function to verify if the given template matches with the template corresponding to the given id*/
    public static int verificaIdentificador(BiometricTemplate template, String id) throws SQLException {

        ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(id);

        if (res.next()) {
            try {

                BiometricTemplate tempBD = new BiometricTemplate((Base64.decode(res.getString("template"))));

                if (tempBD.match(template) > minimumThreshold) {
                    return 1;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /*Given a ID, tries to find correspondent template*/
    public static String findIDTemplate(BiometricTemplate template) throws SQLException {

        if (con == null) {
            connectToDB();
        }
        if (stm == null) {
            stm = con.createStatement();
        }

        String query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios";
        ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery(query);


        /*prepares identification context to perform match faster*/
        BiometricIdentification temp = new BiometricIdentification(template);

        while (res.next()) {
            try {
                //retrieves template 
                BiometricTemplate tempBD = new BiometricTemplate((Base64.decode(res.getString("Template"))));

                //checks if match score is higher than minimum threshold                    
                if (temp.match(tempBD) > 40) {
                    return res.getString("id");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        return null;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dbAccess.connectToDB();
    }

    public static void connectToDB() {

        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String userName = "root";
            String password = "12rafael34";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.51.199//";
            String dbName = "survey";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
            stm = con.createStatement();
            stm.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS template");
            stm.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE template ("
                    + "id varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
                    + "template varchar(1000) NOT NULL,"
                    + "nome varchar(1000) NOT NULL);");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static BiometricTemplate getAddtemplate() {
        return AddTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse erro ocorre em qual momento exatamente? No código que você compartilhou o `main` apenas chama o `connectToDB()`, que por sua vez apenas parece tentar criar o banco.